# How to reduce TextBox dimension

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using the `MDIX` framework which provide a `Style` resource called `MaterialDesignTextFieldBoxTextBox`. When I apply that style I'll get a very big dimension for the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextFieldBoxTextBox}" />
```

[image]

(I don't know why the image doesn't appear.)

Anyway, I want to reduce the height of that control. I tried using this code:

```
 <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{DynamicResource search}">
     <TextBox.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextFieldBoxTextBox}">
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
       </Style>
     </TextBox.Resources>
 </TextBox>
```

with this the `hint` will disappear:

[image]

how can I handle that?

Comment: I would dig through the source code and take a look at what it does. There's a forum of some sort if you mean this https://gitter.im/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit?at=5a2a01baa2be46682874f082

Comment: hope someone of mdix will answer here, I added the mdix tag

Comment: On the off chance they don't visit stackoverflow ( sacrilege ! ). You might want to consider also posting in any forum they usually hang out in.

Comment: You'll just need to edit the style template you're referencing. From the looks of it they probably just have a hard set padding in their template that's cutting off the ContentPresenter inside it which is why your hint disappears. Try adding `<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>` to your override. Otherwise you'll need to go look at their template structure.

Comment: @ChrisW. Tried, same result.

Comment: Can you share a link to wherever you're getting this stuff from? A quick peek at their template would likely reveal your culprit real easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with MDIX v2.4.0 (latest).

If you look at the style on its own without any changes you get something like this:
[image]

There are three MDIX styles worth looking at here:

1. `MaterialDesignTextBox` is the [base TextBox style](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L12) in MDIX.
2. `MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox` derives from `MaterialDesignTextBox` and [sets `HintAssist.IsFloating` to true](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L203). This is that floating blue "Search" text from the above image.
3. `MaterialDesignTextAreaTextBox` derives from `MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox`and [sets `TextFieldAssist.HasTextAreaBox` to true](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L211).

The biggest issue with manually setting the height to be shorter is that gray area around the text box. That is turned on when you set `TextFieldAssist.HasTextAreaBox=true`. This area is simply a [border control](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L53) when that property gets set to true, it [sets several properties on that border](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L113-L126). Specifically note the margin and padding setters. These are all making assumptions about a particular minimum size. 
The other issue is the `HintAssist.IsFloating=true`. When you set this it [allocates some of the space](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L99-L101) around the text box for displaying the hint.

With both of these properties enabled, you will not be able to reduce the size of the text box down to 30 and still have all of those features work. You can simply turn them, off but at that point you are left with the base `MaterialDesignTextBox` style.

I think something like this is what you want.

```
<TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

If you want to enable the floating hint or the text area border you will need to increase the height.

**EDIT:**
If you want to simulate the look of the the the text area border you can wrap the TextBox in a border like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTextFieldBoxBackground}" Padding="0,0,0,4">
    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
</Border>
```

Comment: So is not possible on the `MaterialDesignTextFieldBoxTextBox` with a low height? How can I make the `MaterialDesignTextBox` gray and with the same corner radius of `MaterialDesignTextFieldBoxTextBox`? Thanks.

Comment: You can wrap the text box in a border that will look very similar. I have editing my response with an example of this.

Comment: just the last question: is possible remove the horizontal gray line of the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions you can use the following option:

```
 <TextBox materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.TextFieldCornerRadius="10"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint =" Name" Style={StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox} />
```